# Set up web services based environment (advice/tips to start)

Tags: java, spring, web-services, mobile

I am a bit lost because it's my first time assuming this role for a project.
We are making a software which consists in an app developed in Phonegap (for making a service oriented architecture, to make multiplatform easier).

The Phonegap app (and also the admin web) will be consuming constantly web services (every functionality is a service), and is my task to set up and environment to publish the API with the different services. I have heard about JAX-RS and also Spring MVC (I prefer this last option, because the good integration with Tomcat, and knowledge on the framework).

I have more or less clear the architecture (Tomcat+Spring+WebServices), but I am not sure how to start, because of the integration with the mobile app. I obviously want to develop with Java in the server side.

Any advice to start or related?

Thanks too much to all.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go for Apache CXF support for Rest Service.You can deploy the same in a tomcat server.I will suggest you to read the following URLs for better understanding:

http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/blog/blog.php?/archives/7-Simple-JAX-RS-Web-Service-in-Java-with-Spring-and-CXF.html

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/restful-services.html

Hope this helps.